# Update column with cumulative values - hardships with query creation

Tags: sql, oracle

So, I had to generate cumulative values for all the records in some groups (SUST-Y01 - 06). And I did it - Output screen and query below.

Query:

```
SELECT
  sust_from, round(percentage_compared_to_sust,2) as percentage_compared_to_sust,
  round(SUM(percentage_compared_to_sust) OVER (PARTITION BY sust_from
  order by sust_from, percentage_compared_to_sust desc),2)
  AS cumulative
FROM table_01;
```

Output:
[Query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziZvW.png)

Difficulties begin when I have to update the table and set the column ACCUMULATE_PERCENTAGE with those query values (as cumulative).

I have tried to write a couple of UPDATE statements but failed every time.
Please, can someone provide me with a good example how this UPDATE should look like?

Comment: which is the unique value column of the table? also add your trial to your question

Comment: You can do this, but you might want to consider whether or not you should do it. This violates normalization rules by putting a derived value that depends on other non-key attributes of the same table. If it is wrong, then you have two disagreeing sources of truth and it won't be clear to future users which is true. It should be best to compute running aggregates like this only at query time rather than store them in the source table. Or at least place them in a special aggregation table that is known to be a derivative/aggregate rather than mix it with the source column(s) in the same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `MERGE` statement and correlate on the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_01 dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid,
         round(
           SUM(percentage_compared_to_sust) OVER (
             PARTITION BY sust_from
             order by sust_from, percentage_compared_to_sust desc
           ),
           2
         ) AS cumulative
  FROM   table_01
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET accumulate_percentage = src.cumulative;
```